# How to replace model associations in-memory in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a Person model, that a Person has many Pets and a Pet has a polymorphic association to Dog and Cat. Note that a person cannot have an animal he/she's allergic to.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
  validate :not_allergic_to_animal

  def not_allergic_to_animal
    if allergic_to_cats? && owns_a_cat?
      errors.add(:pets, 'cannot have a cat if allergic to cats')
    elsif allergic_to_dogs? && owns_a_dog?
      errors.add(:pets, 'cannot have a dog if allergic to dogs')
    end
  end

  def owns_a_cat?
    pets.any? { |pet| pet.animal_type == Cat.name }
  end

  def owns_a_dog?
    pets.any? { |pet| pet.animal_type == Dog.name }
  end
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :animal, polymorphic: true

  validates :animal_type, inclusion: { in: [Cat.name, Dog.name] } 
end

class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now let's say the Person Bob already has 2 cats, one named Alice and the other one named Adele.

```
bob = Person.where(name: 'Bob')

alice = Cat.where(name: 'Alice')
bob.pets.create!(animal: alice)

adele = Cat.where(name: 'Adele')
bob.pets.create!(animal: adele)
```

Bob likes Alice, but Adele is a really agressive cat, so Bob doesn't want it anymore. He also wants a dog. Therefore, he decides to do a PUT request to his endpoint. 3 is the id of Jack the dog and 1 is the id of Alice the cat.

```
PUT /me/ {
  "pets": {
    "dog_ids": [3],
    "cat_ids": [1]
  }
}
```

Now the question!

*How can I replace Bob's pets in memory, validate Bob to be sure he's not allergic to any of his pets and then save the associations (without using a database transaction)?*

I know it's possible to create associations in memory using `#build`, but I don't want to append to existing associations but **replace** the existing ones, all **in memory** before saving. Therefore the example above would do 2 database queries after the Person instance has been validated, one to create the Pet association for Jack the dog and the other one to remove the association for Adele the cat, **after** validation.

I tried manipulating `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` but it always commit in the database when removing or adding an element.

Note that I dont want to create a param validator and just validate ids either, other interfaces can be used to update a Person, and the validation needs to be consistent across all those interfaces and close to the model.

**Edit**

I tried using `#build` in conjunction with `#mark_for_destruction` as well, but then replacing won't work, the existing associations will be recreated upon saving.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I just came with:

mark for destruction pets for which `animal_id` is not in the provided ids, build animals that don't already exist and skip animals marked for destruction in validation.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
  validate :not_allergic_to_animal

  def not_allergic_to_animal
    if allergic_to_cats? && owns_a_cat?
      errors.add(:pets, 'cannot have a cat if allergic to cats')
    elsif allergic_to_dogs? && owns_a_dog?
      errors.add(:pets, 'cannot have a dog if allergic to dogs')
    end
  end
  def owns_a_cat?
    pets
      .reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)
      .any? { |pet| pet.animal_type == Cat.name }
  end

  def owns_a_dog?
    pets
      .reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)
      .any? { |pet| pet.animal_type == Dog.name }
  end
end


bob = Person.where(name: 'Bob')

alice = Cat.where(name: 'Alice')
bob.pets.create!(animal: alice)

adele = Cat.where(name: 'Adele')
bob.pets.create!(animal: adele)

jack = Dog.create

bob.pets.find_by(animal_type: Cat.name, animal_id: adele.id).mark_for_destruction

bob.pets.build(animal: jack)
bob.valid?
bob.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the collection directly by using `pets=` method. For example,

```
# Find the first pet
p1 = bob.pets.find_by_animal_id(alice.id)

# Create the second pet, this won't save yet
jack = Dog.find(3)
p2 = Pet.new(animal: jack)

bob.pets = [p1, p2]
```

Comment: doing `bob.pets = [p1, p2]` will save the pets association in the database. I want to assign the pets to bob in memory to validate bob before doing any database transaction. In theory it is clearly possible, but ActiveRecord does not let me do it.